# only allow rotation of one subplot

Tags: matlab

I have two subplots.  One is 3D and rotation is useful, but the 2nd is 2D and I keep accidentally rotating it which is really annoying.  Is it possible to only allow rotation of one subplot?

Comment: Some code to demonstrate the issue might help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are turning on plot rotation using the [image] button on the figure toolbar. Instead of pressing this button, which turns on rotation for all axes in the figure window, you can simply call the function [ROTATE3D](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rotate3d.html) in your code:

```
rotate3d(hAxes);  %# Turn on rotation for axes with handle hAxes
```

Where `hAxes` is the [handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html) of the axes (i.e. subplot) you want to turn rotation on for. An axes handle is usually returned by functions that create them (like [AXES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes.html) or [SUBPLOT](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html)), or it can be found using the functions [GCA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gca.html) (for the currently active axes) or [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html).

Here are a couple alternative ways to call [ROTATE3D](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rotate3d.html) to turn on rotation, each of which achieves the same as the above line of code:

```
%# Option 1:
rotate3d(hAxes,'on');  %# Explicitly state 'on' (no argument will simply toggle)
%# Option 2:
h = rotate3d(hAxes);   %# Create a rotate mode object with handle h for hAxes
set(h,'Enable','on');  %# Enable rotation
```

Comment: You must call rotate3d(hSubPlot,'on'); after creating the last subplot.